# Clang error on makefile execution of make

Tags: c, makefile

So I have two `C` files which are `master.c`, `slave.c` and then `config.h` and I'm trying to build a makefile for the execution of these files and I'm getting an error.

I'm using a normal terminal on MacOS and when executing `make` I get the following error:

```
ss@US3FHIM0XQ86TJG: ~/project-2[master*]$ make
gcc -o master config.h master.c -g -I -std=gnu99
clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
make: *** [master] Error 1
```

Here is what my makefile looks like:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -I -std=gnu99

all: master slave

master: config.h master.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

slave: config.h slave.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm master slave cstest logfile.*
```

Can someone spot what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Do not compile .h files.

Comment: @273K, wow, that worked! Is there a reason behind not compiling .h files? I would like to learn since I'm just beginning with C.

Comment: @273K, for which part specifically? The `$@ $^` part?

Comment: Ahh, thank you! So even without compiling the .h files, the .c files will know to include the .h file, correct?

Comment: .c files knows nothing, you use #include directive to direct the file to include the content of a .h file.

Answer (score 0):

`$^` is a placeholder for the list of dependencies. That is why the rule

```
master: config.h master.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

runs the command

```
gcc -o master config.h master.c -g -I -std=gnu99
```

Compiling .h produces one output, compiling .c produces another output. The compiler does not know to which of them to apply -o. The proper way is using rules

```
master: master.c config.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

slave: slave.c config.h
    $(CC) -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

`$<` is a placeholder for the first item in the list of dependencies. These rules run gcc properly

```
gcc -o master master.c -g -I -std=gnu99
gcc -o slave slave.c -g -I -std=gnu99
```

Comment: Thanks @273K, I just made the update to the makefile, but I'm getting this error `makefile:7: *** missing separator.  Stop.` when attempting `make clean`.

Comment: make expects the tab, but you get spaces after copy-paste

Answer (score 0):

Remove config.h. You can compile it on the command line and omit "config.h", ie:

gcc -o master master.c -g -I -std=gnu99

Some people like to put that -o at the end:

gcc -g -I -std=gnu99 -c master.c -o master

A more appropriate way would be:

gcc -g -I/usr/include -std=gnu99 -c master.c -o master

Generally, the -I has a path, such as -I/usr/include, but you can omit the -I as your compiler usually looks there first.

Also, you may have to tweak your Makefile and omit the config.h if it is happening when you type make.

Some little errors you can fix by compiling the object by hand (ie, as above, gcc -g -I/usr/include -std=gnu99 -c master.c -o master)

Once you edit Makefile and remove config.h, and perhaps use -I/usr/include or path to your headers, you can run:

make clean

make all

or just:

make slave

or:

make master

etc, etc